# Broken vanilla RabbitMQ installation on Windows 10

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-10

I installed Erlang and RabbitMQ as instructed at https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html. And yes I installed Erlang as Admin user.

But somehow the installation is broken.

```
rabbitmqctl.bat status
```

gives

```
Status of node rabbit@K21788 ...
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@K21788'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

...

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@K21788]

rabbit@K21788:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on K21788
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  other nodes on K21788: ['RabbitMQ']
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-1196-rabbit@K21788'
 * effective user's home directory: H:\
 * Erlang cookie hash: /xiNRP3ci4Ddvw0WKmq9Dw==
```

Strange, de node default name seams to be wrong.

So I tried:

```
rabbitmqctl.bat -n RabbitMQ status
Status of node RabbitMQ@K21788 ...
Error:
{:undef, [{:rabbit, :status, [], []}, {:rpc, :"-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-", 5, [file: 'rpc.erl', line: 197]}]}
```

As a RabbitMQ rookie I feal pretty much lost here. On my Macbook this just works without any problems.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: That's very strange and I have never seen this issue. I have installed RabbitMQ on my Windows 10 and 8.1 VMs many times to test without this issue. If you installed Erlang and RabbitMQ via their `.exe` installers from an elevated prompt I can't see how this could happen. You wouldn't happen to have any `RABBITMQ_*` environment variables defined? I can't think of much else that would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error I found this workaround:

1. Stop the preinstalled windows service "RabbitMQ".
2. If you want you can disable autostart as well.
3. Open a cmd-Shell.
4. Go to `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.14\sbin`
5. Start the server with `rabbitmq-server.bat`.

Now RabbitMQ starts with the correct defaults. All my Java Examples from the tutorial work as expected.

I don't know why this works and the preinstalled Service does not. But for my dev environment this solution is fine.